# Is it possible to write multi-platform program that is not writen in Java

Tags: programming-languages, cross-platform, multiplatform

Just curious, is it possible to write a multi-platform program that is not writen in Java.

If true, could I do it by compiling two or three different programing languages (for each platform) together so that it would run on different platforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-platform

C++ is the traditional cross-platform language. However, there are many other popular choices such as Python.

Answer (score 4):

[Python](http://www.python.org/) is a multi-platform language, available for all the usual platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Mono offers you the opportunity to write multiplatform applications in C#.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29:

> Mono can be run on Linux, BSD, UNIX,
>   Mac OS X, Solaris and Windows
>   operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

[Pharo](http://www.pharo-project.org) is multiplatform.

It uses the Smalltalk language, which is object-oriented.

There is a free introduction book, [Pharo by Example](http://www.pharobyexample.org).

Comment: I routinely develop on both a Mac and a XP machine, and deploy to Linux

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight is multi-platform and can be run out-of-browser.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [ANSI C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C). This standard is supported by virtually every known platform and architecture, and you can go just about anywhere with it. However, one must *strictly* comply with the ANSI C standard as if one doesn't you will almost always introduce some level of platform dependence.

Answer (score 1):

The web, surely! Any web-application can run on any device with a web-browser and an Internet connection. This is probably the "future" of cross-platform development. And your users don't even have to install anything.

Comment: Then they write programs that hook into specific browsers (IE6 springs to mind) and ruin the whole idea....

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of non-Java cross-platform languages. C/C++, C# (using Mono), Python, PHP, Perl... Even Visual Basic has a cross platform implementation (http://www.mono-project.com/VisualBasic.NET_support).